# How to get rid of 100% calculations in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns

I am trying to display on time performance as a percentage using a calculated column in PowerBI but when I filter the dates on my dashboard, all months or weeks outside of the filter display as 100% rather than disappearing like all other visuals on the dashboard. Even more strange is when using a line and clustered column chart, it works fine but does not work properly with a line chart.

This is my calculated column formula: `Controllable On-Time = 1-(CALCULATE(COUNT('Order Data Query'[QC Code]),FILTER('QC Code Key','QC Code Key'[Controllable?] = "Controllable")) / COUNT('Order Data Query'[Job ID]))`

[When using a date filter, anything outside of the filter displays as 100% rather than disappearing like all other visuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QokyX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Review your column formula:

```
Controllable On-Time = 1-(CALCULATE(COUNT('Order Data Query'[QC Code]),FILTER('QC Code Key','QC Code Key'[Controllable?] = "Controllable")) / COUNT('Order Data Query'[Job ID]))
```

we can simplify it as:

```
Controllable On-Time = 1 - X
```

therefore, when X = 0, then

```
Controllable On-Time = 1
```

hence, it is a constant value always equal to 1 (or 100% if formatted as percentage).

Comment: I understand the math behind it. What I dont understand is why PowerBI visual displays 100% rather than disappearing like all other visuals do when the date is filtered. A typical interaction is to not display dates outside of the date filter given but this measure somehow still displays outside of the date filters applied to the page.

Comment: The explanation is in my answer. The measure is defined as a constant always equal to 1. Does this help to make the explanation more clear?